# Build old node on Freebsd shared hosting

Tags: freebsd, compiling, node.js

We have an access to ssh on our shared hosting account. Sysadmin informed us that he will remove the old version of node soonish, hence if we want to still use it, we have to create our local copy. The problem is that we are not familiar with FreeBSD/node.

Could someone lead us how to build https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/v6.17.1 step by step for only one user (without root privillages), please? I have seen instruction: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md but I'm not even sure which file from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/ I should download and extract...

> $ uname -a
>
> FreeBSD subdomain.rxample.com 11.3-RELEASE-p12 FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p12 #2: Thu Aug  6 06:20:05 CEST 2020

fyi upgrading the project to make it compatible with more up to date node versions unfortunatelly it's not an option here.

---

**Update:**

We have downloaded and unpacked: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/node-v6.17.1.tar.gz

Then we have ran:

```
$ ./configure
$ make -j4
```

what are the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from the source

Here's the tar.gz file on the nodejs.org site: [V6 tar.gz](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/node-v6.17.1.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

Node version 6 is still in ports at `/usr/ports/www/node6` and can be installed from there.

Also see:
[The FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html) - [FreeBSD Porter's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/) - [FreeBSD Developer's Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/)

Comment: unfortunatelly we are using shared hosting, so we don't have an access neither to `/usr` nor to `sudo `

Comment: @Michal_Szulc You can still download and install the port from the FreeBSD site but I don't know if you would need root to run it. I'll find the link.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc I see that the port downloads version 6 from node itself. Since you have it, you can use the Makefile and other files from the port to help install version 6.